# SQL Fetch Query execute to slow in both server on local as well as on azure

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT Users.Id,
       Users.IsActive,
       Users.Risk,
       Users.Name,
       Users.EmployeeID,
       Users.OrganizationId,
       Users.Username,
       Users.IsUser,
       Users.WFID,
       Organizations.Name AS orgName,
       (SELECT MAX(UserTestGroups.ModifiedOn)
        FROM UsersInSchedules
        LEFT JOIN UserTestGroups ON UsersInSchedules.Id = UserTestGroups.UserInScheduleID
        WHERE Users.Id = UsersInSchedules.UserID) AS LastTest
FROM Users
LEFT JOIN Organizations ON Users.OrganizationID = Organizations.Id
WHERE Users.isUser = '0'
      AND Users.IsDeleted = '0'
ORDER BY Users.Name ASC
OFFSET 15 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```

Above query is working too slowly, taking almost 7 seconds to respond from server.

I am not understanding why that is happening - what is wrong with the query?

Here is the execution plan for query:

[image: Please go through execution plan let me know if I am doing anything wrong in this query]

Comment: How many rows you have? Any indexes beside PK's clustered indexes? Is it estimated or actual plan? What about statistics?

Comment: please share execution plan as xml and test data to further repro the issue along with table definitons involved

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: I'm sure you asked about this yesterday! I would make sure you have a composite index for at least everything in your WHERE clause and ORDER BY clause

Answer (score 0):

The nested *SELECT* could be the reason for low performance of your query. The nested *SELECT* must be processed for each result of your outer query. I think a join approach could yield better result. You could try

```
SELECT Users.Id,
       Users.IsActive,
       Users.Risk,
       Users.Name,
       Users.EmployeeID,
       Users.OrganizationId,
       Users.Username,
       Users.IsUser,
       Users.WFID,
       Organizations.Name AS orgName,
       UserTest.LastTest
FROM Users
    LEFT JOIN Organizations ON Users.OrganizationID = Organizations.Id
    LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT UsersInSchedules.UserID, MAX(UserTestGroups.ModifiedOn) AS LastTest
        FROM UsersInSchedules
        LEFT JOIN UserTestGroups ON UsersInSchedules.Id = UserTestGroups.UserInScheduleID
        GROUP BY UsersInSchedules.UserID
        ) UserTest ON Users.Id = UserTest.UserID
WHERE Users.isUser = '0' AND Users.IsDeleted = '0'
ORDER BY Users.Name ASC
OFFSET 15 ROWS FETCH NEXT 15 ROWS ONLY
```